# how to set paper-dialog show on the whole page

Tags: polymer

In my application,I use Polymer.The application is made up with the left part and the right part. there is a button in the right part,when the button is clicked,the paper-dialog will appear on the right part.But I want it on in the whole page.How do I do?

the code is blow...

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">

        <paper-dialog id="allActAddModal"  style="width:80%;max-height:90%;margin-top:-2.5%" with-backdrop>
                   <act-create-all id="actAdd" on-save-ok="handleSaveOkTapped">
                    </act-create-all>
            </paper-dialog>

    <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red" on-click="handleAddAct">
                        <i class="large mdi-content-add"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

        handleAddAct: function(event) {
            this.$.allActAddModal.toggle();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer neon-animataion exist demo when grid transform to half page. You can use this example to resolve your task.

Foe help you in bower write next

```
"neon-elements": "PolymerElements/neon-elements#master",
"web-animations-js": "web-animations/web-animations-js#2.0.0"
```

And in bower_components/neon-animation/demo/grid you can find what you need.

P.S
"web-animations-js": "web-animations/web-animations-js#2.0.0" need to resolve bug in Google Chrome when animation don't work